# Getting ts errors in a js file

Tags: node.js, typescript, zeromq, tsconfig

I have a project with the following ts config. However when I run the nodejs server and use zeromq, I get Typescript errors in node_modules\zeromq\lib\index.js where export.Context (line 755) doesn't exists and zmqVersion() (line 19) is not a function. I do have ts set to ignore nodejs modules.

When I look at the ts files `npx tsc --listFiles` zeromq and other node_mods are not listed. So I am not sure why I am getting *ts* errors in zeromq. It's the only module that I am having issues with.

I do have @types/zeromq installed, but I still see these errors in the js file.

**Reproducing**:

tsconfig file:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./distTemp/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "checkJs": false,            // <-I added this to try
    "allowJs": true,             // <-I added this to try
    "skipLibCheck": true,        // <-I added this to try
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true, // <-I added this to try
    "types": ["zeromq"]          // <-I added this to try
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  },
  "lib": ["esnext"],
  "paths": [
    "global.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": ["./src", "./server.ts"],
  "exclude": ["./node_modules", "./build", "./dist", "./src/**/*.js", "./src/**/*.jsx"]
}
```

"I added this to try" are the lines I added to try and fix this issue. I run the code with

```
node -r ts-node/register server.ts --development
```

This has been really frustrating. I like zeromq and have used it before in different languages - I am really annoyed at the ts functionality here. After all this is a JS file.

Also this wasn't always popping up. I did have this running at one point. But to my knowledge no packages were updated, so I am not sure what change caused this.

Comment: In my experience, `ts-node` has been extremely frustrating to work with (and sometimes doesn't read your tsconfig.json). I typically use `tsc -w` and then run the compiled output. Maybe it'll help with your situation as well. I suspect `ts-node` is not respecting your tsconfig here.

Comment: Ts-node is supposed to load config files exactly the way tsc does. However for good measure, try `ts-node --project tsconfig.json server.ts`

Comment: Tried the two commands above and I am still seeing the zmqVersion() is not a function TS error unfortunately.